# Athena gets order of operations wrong

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

What is Athena doing here?

```
select
(10.0*12+10/10000)
```

It returns a value of 120.0

I know it's not rounding off because the "10" and the "12" in my code are small fractions < 0.01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got struck by another case of integer division. `10/10000` is calculated before the sum and type of `10/10000` result is determined by the types taking part in the division, hence `select typeof(10/10000)` is `integer`, change one of operands to be double (potentially with correct precision):

```sql
select (10.0*12 + 10.000/10000);
```

Output:

```
  _col0  
---------
 120.001
```